# how use annotation Instead loop on filter

Tags: django, django-models

i use a table Bid in this table have multi fields and a field named user other hand have a Dealer table that save users in Dealer_serializer i have a bids_count serializer Method Field that return each user count in Bid table i want use annotate instead of loop over filter! to get each user how many in Bid Table.
if my idea not true explain me what exactly doing annotation?

```
class Dealer(User):
    car_exhibition = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey('locations.City', blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=500)

class Bid(models.Model):
    auction = models.ForeignKey('Auction')
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User')
    step = models.BigIntegerField()
    price = models.BigIntegerField()

created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: It's better to provide a code snippet rather than describing it. Please paste your `models`.

Comment: paste models the end of comments

Comment: Dealer inherit from django user table that have username , id, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the relation of your `Dealer` with `Bid`. But for `User` you can use annotation:

```
User.objects.annotate(bids_count=Count('bid')).values('id', 'bids_count')
```

As a result you will have:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'bids_count': 3}, {'id': 2, 'bids_count': 10}, ..., >
```

Where `id` is `user_id` and `bid_count` is how many `Bids` are related to `User` with that `id`. 
I hope this is what you are going to achieve. Please comment in case of any questions.